# Serving media files from nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

**BREAKDOWN OF THE CURRENT PROBLEM:**

I had created a site with django, that was serving media files uploaded in the admin correctly(as I believed it was), because they appeared at the respective page once uploaded. However, after some new site fixes, these files stopped showing up, and the images and audio would not appear.

To host my site I am using Digital Ocean.

If I set the MEDIA_URL to '/media/' it keeps getting prepended to the STATIC URL, and the URL would look like "www.site.com/media/static/Images/etc', and then nothing works properly.

In my models, for the ImageField() I have upload_to set as

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/")
```

**MY urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^' + ADMIN + '/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('a.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('b.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('c.urls')),
    #for static files
] #+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This creates a folder inside my media folder which is at the root directory where my django app is located.

I read in the documentation, but I am still unclear on how to do things when it comes to serving my media files when it is uploaded. I know the right way to do it, is to serve them using a server like nginx.

I would like to know why my media files where not showing originally, and if I should use nginx will the fact that the files in the media folder, are said to not be found, will it affect how nginx displays the files, and 
why is it that the media url gets prepended?

I will do the nginx configuration, but if you care to show an example, please do.

THANK YOU!

**My respective URLS in Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/path/to/project/static'
MEDIA_URL = '/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get my files to display on my production website, but it involved a little work around. Since I knew that files that were already in the static folder were being collected and displayed, all I had to do was put the user files in the static folder.

**So I did this:**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT),
    'media',
)
```

Now, collectstatic goes into the folder and gets the media files that were uploaded. The only problem is that every time I upload a file, I have to run collectstatic, therefore this is a temporary fix. If you know how to make the collectstatic run automatically every time a file is uploaded please comment below.

I just thought I would share this, just in case someone had the same issue and wanted a temporary fix.

Comment: This is wrong. Don't confuse static files with media files. Static files are part of your program, like your css, javascript, and any images that are part of your program. Media files are data, uploaded by users. For static files, see https://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/. Media files should go to another directory (and there's no such thing as `collectstatic` for media files).

Comment: @AntonisChristofides was able to collect the media files by collecting the files in the media folder. Do you know any tutorials that can point me to how to do this the right way. I am just really confused, and I cant really stop working on this, until I figure it out. The django documentation on deploying static files does not mention how to deal with media files.

Comment: "was able to collect the media files by collecting the files" doesn't make much sense. You need to explain exactly what you are doing. Better use an example of a single file. Which file it is, to what model does it correspond, in which directory did you put it, how did you put it there, and problem are you having?